# Wordpress Options framework check variable isset

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this library http://wptheming.com/options-framework-theme/ for creating a theme option page in my admin panel in wordpress.

I want to know How can I check the variable that if the value is inserted on the input box or not

right now I am printing the value like this

```
<?php echo of_get_option('title', '');?>
```

I want to do like this

```
   if(isset($title)){
 <?php echo of_get_option('title', '');?>
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just `$title = of_get_option('title', ''); if(!empty($title)) echo $title;`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<?php if (of_get_option('title')) {?>
    <?php echo $title ?>
<?php } else { ?>
    <?php echo "No Title Submitted in Options Framework" ?>
<?php } ?>
```